# find sum of numbers automatically as user inputs values dynamically irrespective of number of inputs.talert user if user enters other than numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

### html code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="elm" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="elm" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="elm" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="elm" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="elm" />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>
                <label id="total">0</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### jquery code

```
$('body').on('keyup','.elm',function(){
var sum = 0;
  $('.elm').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '' && !isNaN($(this).val())){
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  });

 $('#total').text(sum);
})
```

i used this code but this is only for 5 inputs .But i need a program which adds unlimited number of user input values dynamically and calculate its output sum automatically  and also  alert the user if user enters other than number.what is the modification i have to do in this code please help me.thank you in advance.

Comment: nothing in the javascript limits it to a maximum of 5 inputs.

Comment: `$(this).val()` is a string. You need to call `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to get a number, and then use `isNan()` on that.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I think he means the HTML limits him to 5 inputs, because he doesn't have JS to add more rows.

Comment: If you want to add more inputs, add an `Add` button at the bottom that appends more rows to the table. The JS for creating the total will work with it automatically.

Comment: what about the two answers. did we get your question right?

Comment: no,i need to to append new rows on pressing enter button in my keyboard and display sum automatically instead of onclick function

Comment: that is a more complex question, you have to take into consideration. what if someone changes the value of a input. so you would not like to add a new row. http://api.jquery.com/focusout is the way to detect the end of an input.

Comment: yes,the new rows were appended but there was no automatic display of sum

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Add Row with enter using the following code.
In the HTML after your `<table>`:

In the JS:

```
var $table = $('table');
var newRow = '<tr><td>Item {{num}}</td><td><input type="text" class="elm" /></td></tr>';
function addRow() {
  var count =$table.find('tr').length + 1;
  $table.append( newRow.replace( '{{num}}', count ) );
}

$('body').on('keyUp', '.elm', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var key = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (key === 13) { //user pressed enter
    addRow();
  } else {
    $('.elm').each(function() {
      var val =$(this).val();
      if( val && !isNaN(val) ){
        sum += parseInt(val,10);
      }
    });
    $('#total').text(sum);
  }
});
```

Comment: @supriya I updated the code to work on keyUp event on any `.elm` element.  Hope that helps.

Comment: i worked on above js file ,i used $(document).ready(function(){ // your js code here // }); to load external js file to html as i am doing in notepad keeping both html and js in one folder by adding links in html like <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script> but its not working.

Comment: @supriya the script tags should be added right before the `</body>` tag in the html.  If they are in the same folder then they should be loaded fine. Are you getting an error in the console?  If so what is it?

Comment: i am executing code in notepad and going to inspect element and then clicking on console i am not getting error.if i execute your code the values what i am entering is also not adding.whats wrong i am doing

Comment: @sanyogita I corrected an error in the code above.  try again and let me know.  Please post error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an Link to produce new rows below your table, and put this into your js-file:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    var itemNr = $('table tr').length;
    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>Item '+itemNr+'</td><td><input type="text" class="elm" /></td></tr>');
});
```

link to a running jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s8f145n/

Or if you want to keep your structure, you can insert it "before" the last row of table instead of "append" it.

```
$('table tr:last').before('<tr><td>Item '+itemNr+'</td><td><input type="text" class="elm" /></td></tr>');
```